# How do I stop \write and \message from inserting a newline at 80 characters?

Tags: symbols, line-breaking, write

I have the following file:

```
\immediate\write16{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL 80 char split is right here -><- this is on the next line}
\message{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL 80 char split is right here -><- this is on the next line}
\end
```

```

Both \write and \message split the line at the indicated point (80 characters). Is there any way to disable that behavior or set the line break point to something really high?

Same behavior happens with tex, etex, pdftex, pdflatex.